# Use of getReturnType() of Java's reflection to create a new object of that type

Tags: java, reflection

I am wondering if I can use the returned type of java's reflection method getReturnType() to create Objects of that type.

I have a method which returns a String, assume that we don't know that at run-time, so I call the `getReturnType()` to determine what type of Objects the method returns:

```
Method myMethod = Book.class.getDeclaredMethod("printName");
Type myType = myMethod.getReturnType();
```

I am wondering if it is possible to use that `myType` to create new Objects or how can I do that? I tried `mytype something = new mytype();` but it is wrong.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to create an *object* of myType or a ***variable*** of myType? Big difference.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry my mistake, Object, using `mytype something   = new mytype();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the [`Method#getReturnType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getReturnType%28%29) is declared as such

```
 Class<?> java.lang.reflect.Method.getReturnType()
```

and the javadoc states that it

> Returns a `Class` object that represents the formal return type of the
>   method represented by this `Method` object.

The `Class` class provides a `newInstance()` method which can use the no argument constructor to create an instance or you can use the [`Class#getDeclaredConstructors()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructors%28%29) method to get a list of `Constructor` instances and use their [`newInstance(Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29) method to create an instance of the class represented.

You won't be able to create a variable of that type since the type is unknown at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

Since the type itself is dynamic you can't declare a variable of that type, this because a declaration is a compile time feature.

Given that, you can istantiate an object of the returned type:

```
try {
  Method myMethod = Book.class.getDeclaredMethod("printName");
  Class<?> type = myMethod.getReturnType();
  Object instance = type.newInstance();
} 
catch (...) {
}
```

The problem is that you can't know the type variable of `getReturnType()` returned `Class`, you just know that this is a `Class<?>` so there's no way to know statically the type of the instance generated by `type.newInstance()`, hence you store it inside an `Object`.